# Is there a mechanism to try to lock one of several mutexes?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

How can a program try to lock multiple mutexes at the same time, and know which mutex it ended up unlocking. Essentially, I am looking for is an equivalent of `select()` but for mutexes. Does such a thing exist? If not, are there any libraries which implement it?

Comment: You could call `pthread_mutex_trylock()` in each mutex in turn? Or is the issue that you'd want it to block until a mutex becomes available?

Comment: That's a busy loop though. Without a `sleep()` call, the thread would use 100% CPU. Also, it is far more efficient to simply block the caller of the `quasy_select()`, and then unblock when one lock has been unlocked.

Comment: Understood. Out of interest, what's the use case?

Comment: Pub/Sub with multiple publishers and one subscriber. I want the subscriber to block when there is no data. The publishers may be publishing at the same time.

Comment: @Maz, this would typically be a condition variable or even a semaphore, mutex isn't the right tool.

Comment: Isn't that the [producer consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) usually solved with [semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html). Publishers are producers, subscriber is consumer - except that it releases the semaphore once he has done [reading?]. And you may have a "cleaner" that removes a "doc" (ie same as subscriber but don't release the sem)

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of the way the producer-consumer problem was typically solved. In any event, my original question still stands: is there a `select()` equivalent for mutexes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm (almost) certain that this kind of functionality ought to be implemented with a monitor (and condition variables using signal/wait/broadcast), but I think you can solve your problem with a single additional semaphore.

Assuming all your mutex objects begin in the "locked" state, create a semaphore with initial value 0. Whenever a mutex object is unlocked, increment (V) the semaphore. Then, implement `select()` like this:

```
 // grab a mutex if possilbe
Mutex select(Semaphore s, Mutex[] m) {
    P(s); // wait for the semaphore
    for (Mutex toTry : m) {
        boolean result = try_unlock(m);
        if (result) return m;
    }
}
```

Essentially, the semaphore keeps track of the number of available locks, so whenever P(s) stops blocking, there must be at least one available mutex (assuming you correctly increment the semaphore when a mutex becomes available!)

I haven't attempted to prove this code correct nor have I tested it... but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Once again, you likely want to use a monitor!